# Is C# Endian sensitive?

Tags: c#, pointers, endianness

Is C# ever Endian sensitive, for example, will code such as this:

```
int a = 1234567;
short b = *(short*)&i;
```

always assign the same value to b. If so, what value will it be?

If not, what good ways are there to deal with endianness if code with pointers in?

Comment: Eeer, you can't do pointer fun in C# :)

Comment: @cwap: If you want to get dirty you can work with pointers in `unsafe` blocks.

Comment: You can with an unsafe block. It's a pretty academic question, because as far as I know there's no implementation of C# on a differently-endian architecture, but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Mono probably has to deal with this stuff.

Comment: You can do pointers in C#, and sometimes I need to for efficiency :(

Comment: Ye, didn't consider those, as Ive never really used them "IRL" :)

Comment: The xbox is the opposite endianness to normal PCs if I remember correctly. Which is pretty important since this is for an XNA networking library (ie. designed for xbox and PC, thus it must run on both). Also, just because there isn't a release of .net for opposite endianness yet doesn't mean there won't ever be.

Comment: the .net microframework runs on all sorts of exotic embedded processors

Comment: "You can do pointers in C#, and sometimes I need to for efficiency" - there's a fix for that, its called C :)

Comment: Loads of pointer stuff happening in [the source for `System.BitConverter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C# doesn't define the endianness. In reality, yes it will probably always be little-endian (IIRC even on IA64, but I haven't checked), but you should ideally check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` if endianness is important - or just use bit-shifting etc rather than direct memory access.

To quote a few lines from protobuf-net (a build not yet committed):

```
WriteInt64(*(long*)&value);
if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{   // not fully tested, but this *should* work
    Reverse(ioBuffer, ioIndex - 8, 8);
}
```

i.e. it checks the endianness and does a flip if necessary.

Comment: Right, so basically work assuming little endian (since that's the most common case) and do a swap before doing direct memory access if necessary?

Comment: @Martin - indeed. Optimise (if appropriate / necessary) for what you *expect*, but ideally support either. Or at least throw an obvious exception at some point.

Comment: Of course, I could put compiler blocks in and have the conditionals at compile time. Since this is something that isn't going to change during the execution of the program ;)

Comment: @Martin - are you always compiling on the same machine that will do the running?

Comment: No, in fact one of the machines is an xbox which of course can't do compilation. But does that matter, if I manually set the target platform endianness and compile?

Comment: @Martin - fine, but *check* it during initialization. i.e. in `Main()` or whatever, **verify** that `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` is what the build expects.

Comment: @Marc: I'm pretty sure @Martin is right on that. PowerPC processors are big endian AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I believe that code *is* endian-sensitive. The value of `b` will be the least-significant bytes on a little-endian processor, and the most-significant bytes on a big-endian processor. To make this simpler to see, let's switch to hex:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    unsafe static void Main()
    {
        int a = 0x12345678;
        short b = *(short*)&a;
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("x"));
    }
}
```

On my x86 box, that prints "5678" showing that the least-significant bytes were at the "start" of the vaue of `a`. If you run the same code on a processor running in big-endian mode (probably under Mono) I'd expect it to print "1234".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, neither the C# nor the Common Language Infrastructure specifications have endianness requirements for pointer-based bitwise and mathematical operations. The CLI does state that binary data stored in a MSIL executable file must be in little endian format. And the general drift of the documents would indicate that code shouldn't be dependent on any specific memory representation (including packed or unpacked arrays, etc.) except under special circumstances.

Answer (score -3):

You really shouldn't be doing pointer swizzling in C#. You should try compiling your code before asking what it will do.

Comment: I know what it does on my particular machine. However, I want to know if it will do the same on _all_ machines. It would be pretty bad practice to run it on my machine and just assume, especially given that I know this is a hardware sensitive issue.
Please try to actually answer the question?

Comment: As mentioned above, pointers are perfectly appropriate in unsafe blocks.

Comment: The answer is "You shouldn't". Cast from `int` to `short` if you want to convert stuff, there is really no reason to do pointer tricks in C#.

Comment: "You shouldn't" eh?  Do you mean that in the same way as "You shouldn't use goto"?

Comment: There is, for example in this case I'm packing 7 bit integers into a 64 bit integer with 1 bit padding. Using pointers is somewhat easier...

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use an array of bytes?

Comment: Yes, the xbox gc is unfortunately rather slow, allocating is generally a bad idea once the game has started, since it would stutter every so often (ie. every GC). I might consider some kind of byte array pooling, but for now I'm designing the system and considering all possibilities