# C# Converting from byte[] to struct. The byte order is wrong

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, byte

I was trying to use a struct to parse socket data when implement a UDP based protocol.
And I searched and I can use these 2 functions to convert between byte[] and struct:

```
 byte[] StructToBytes(object structObj)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(structObj);
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(structObj, buffer, false);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
            Marshal.Copy(buffer, bytes, 0, size);
            return bytes;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        }

    }

    static object BytesToStruct(byte[] bytes, Type strcutType, int offset = 0)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(strcutType);
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, offset, buffer, size);
            return Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, strcutType);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        }
    }
```

Then I had this problem:

```
//I defined a simple struct with an ushort member
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
    struct S
    {
        public ushort a;
    }

    //Then I define a byte[]
    byte[] bArr;
    bArr[0] = 0;
    bArr[1] = 1;

    //Convert to struct
    S s = (S)BytesToStruct(bArr, typeof(S));
    //Then s.a = 0x0100 not 0x0001
```

And struct to byte[] is just the same. The 2 bytes of ushort are reversed.
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most processors these days use Little-Endian byte ordering (Least significant byte comes first). Network byte ordering is traditional Big-Endian, so you usually need to mirror the byte order. You can check the endianness of the system with `System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`

The .Net equivalent of ntohs() Frank mentioned is located (oddly) at `System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder()`

You could also write your own mechanism to read the bytes in the correct order directly, using bit shifting and logical OR.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between network byte order and host byte order.

Typically, in C at least, you use ntohl(), ntohs() and friends to convert network byte order to your host order when reading from a socket.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to do with the endianness of `short` on your system. Have a look at [this question about endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247907/is-c-endian-sensitive), which may provide some pointers (pun unintentional).

Also, I would suggest making `BytesToStruct` generic in the type of the `struct`:

```
static S BytesToStruct<S>(byte[] bytes, int offset = 0)
```

so it could be called with

```
BytesToStruct<S>(bArr)
```

rather than as at present

```
(S)BytesToStruct(bArr, typeof(S))
```